# Python urllib module: iterating over URL

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to fetch the last 5 characteres from the page's html text and use them to replace the last 5 characteres in the url, and try again. I need to repeat this a number of times.

This is what I've come up with. At the moment, it prints the same url 5 times in a row.

```
import urllib.request

prevurl = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345"
for i in range(1,5):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(prevurl) as url:
        s = url.read()
        prevurl.replace('[-5:]', 's[-5:]')
    print(prevurl)
```

Comment: ummm... check what you're replacing there... you shouldn't have any quote characters there

Comment: It seems that removing the quotes makes the syntax invalid

Comment: Try this `prevurl = prevurl.replace(prevurl[:-5], s[-5:])`

Comment: New error. "TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not bytes". Do I have to convert `s` first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the negativations. I could use some constructive criticism instead. Great way to encourage learning.

Anyways, I think I figured it out. It takes some extra steps, but works just the way I wanted.

```
import urllib.request

prevurl = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345"
for i in range(1,400):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(prevurl) as url:
        s = url.read().decode("utf-8")
        n1 = []
        u1 = []
        for i in s:
            if i.isdigit():
                n1.append(i)
                n2 = ''.join(n1)
        for i in prevurl:
            if i.isdigit():
                u1.append(i)
                u2 = ''.join(u1)
        if len(n2) != len(u2):
            prevurl = prevurl.replace(prevurl[-(len(u2)):], n2)
        else:
            prevurl = prevurl.replace(prevurl[-(len(n2)):],n2)

    print(prevurl)
```